# Why is this CATiledLayer/PDF code slow?

Tags: iphone, performance, pdf, catiledlayer

Here is the code:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/o42wy36x4qhrbpt/PDFScroller.zip

I took the WWDC 2010 `PhotoScroller` sample code that implements nested `UIScrollViews` for zooming, inside a `UIScrollView` for paging, and swapped out what I thought would be minimal amount of code required for displaying a multi-page PDF instead of images.

It works. But it's slow on my iPhone4, about three seconds to paint the first page, and even slower on my iPod Touch. I can watch it painting the individual tiles. This same PDF already opens up more quickly, with no visible tile drawing, in an alternate `CATiledLayer` implementation I have which simply uses a single `CATiledLayer`/`UIScrollView` and touch events to change pages. I'd like to use this `PhotoScroller` technique, it's very nice.

I watched it with CPU Sampler in Instruments, and it doesn't seem to be the PDF rendering code, it looks like the time is taken up in threading and messaging. I'd appreciate it if someone could help point out what this sample is doing to incur the overhead.

Thanks,

Jim

---

Update 1: I had originally used the `TilingView` class technique from the sample code of defining

```
+ (Class) layerClass {
  return [CATiledLayer class];
}
```

And then drawing in `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` but switched to the explicit `CATiledLayer` subclass as a first attempt at seeing whether it would make a difference, but it did not, and so I left the code as-is for posting here.  There is also a missing `[tiledLayer release];` leak in TilingView.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for it? I was working on the same.

Comment: Yes, increasing the tile size improves performance significantly.

Comment: Got it, just added a new line in the code: tiledLayer.tileSize = CGSizeMake(512, 512); Worked really well! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this Thread [Fast and Lean PDF Viewer for iPhone / iPad / iOs - tips and hints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-how-does-ibooks-do-it) for PDF rendering tips.

Answer (score 2):

as your code contains couple of errors and i can not compile the code, but i took a look at the PDF file which was included in the archive and i know the reason why your TilingView is slow.

Normally when you draw a pdf page in a `CGContext` using the method `CGContextDrawPDFPage`:, all text and vectorial graphics were rendered and other things like normal graphics in the PDF are just get drawn and cached. So it does not matter how big the PDF file is, but it does matter if you have vectorial grahics in your PDF. It seems that you have some vectorial graphic in your PDF and also some math equations, that's the reason why it is slow. I suggest you to try with another PDF file which does not contain vectorial graphics and see if it is faster.

Cheers

Zheng

Comment: Zheng, thanks for your response.  On my computer the code builds and runs with the latest iOS 4.0.2 SDK.  And as far as the content of the PDF file goes, unfortunately, I don't get to choose which PDF my users decide to try to view, I must simply do my best with any valid PDF document.

Answer (score 1):

Conjecture not to be taken with any sort of authority: PDF *is* a vector based format for most documents (excluding those that simply serve as a container for embedded TIFF images). So when you tile the PDF like the PhotoScroller, you essentially ask the phone to scale and rasterize the whole PDF (well at least the given page) for each individual tile. So rather than painting it once as you might for a single CATiledLayer, you do it multiple times for each resolution. Since the PDF is a scalable format in itself, you should be able to simply render the entire view once for each page/scale.

**Update:** Having just gone through this myself, the PhotoScroller sample has some logic issues that make it very slow. Basically it renders the each tile at 1/zoomScale then scales is back down to zoomScale. So if zoom is at .5 it renders at **2x** then scales that back down to 0.5x. Very slow an inefficient.

Comment: Agreed, and the CATiledLayer should be taking care of that for you, right? It would be nice to have some diagnostic output, or even a delegate API from that class to let us know how the caching behaves, according to the properties we set: tile size, detail, detail bias. I suppose they need room to tweak the algorithm.